# Django default entries on model creation

Tags: django, django-models

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I cannot find the answer. In django, if I have this model

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

How would one populate this model with a default `Person` entry when the first migrating the field?

I'm not talking about default values for the fields, but for default entries in the database.

thanks

Comment: Do you want to initialize your Person model from your database? You create models to tell django that these tables exists in your DB or to create these tables (in case you havent already run make-migrations) so there are other ways to do that. Did i get your question right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a [*data migration*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations), that follows on the migration where you create the `Person` object. You can first let Django write the "skeleton" of the migration, this can be done with:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty appname
```

Next Django will make a file. In that file you can add `RunPython` item to the `operations` list. This then obtain the *historical* model (the model at that moment of the migration), where you then create a `Person` object in the database. For example with:

```
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    def create_person(apps, schema_editor):
        Person = apps.get_model('appname', 'Person')
        Person.objects.create(first_name='will', last_name='mendil')

    dependencies = [
        ('appname', 'migrationname'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_person)
    ]
```