# How to add default data to django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a web app with the following model

```
class Records(models.Model):
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=17, unique=True)
    status = models.BooleanField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.alias

    def list_data(self):
        return [self.alias, self.status, self.created_at, self.updated_at]
```

I want some default data to be populated into this model on creation. I went through the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) and this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61685032/django-default-entries-on-model-creation) for doing the same.

I first ran this command to create a migrations file (0001_initial.py)

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty main_app
```

I then edited the migrations file as follows
0001_initial.py

```
# Generated by Django 4.0.3 on 2022-04-23 05:57

from django.db import migrations

def add_initial_data(apps, schema_editor):

    Records = apps.get_model('main_app', 'Records')
    for record in Records.objects.all():
        record.alias = f'ACCORD1'
        record.status = True
        record.save()
        
        for i in range(2,6):
            record.alias = f'ACCORD{i}'
            record.status = False
            record.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(add_initial_data)
    ]
```

When I run the migrations with the following command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I get the following error

```
LookupError: No installed app with label 'main_app'.
```

I tried adding the dependency to the migrations file as follows

```
dependencies = [
        ('main_app', '0001_initial')
    ]
```

But this gives me the following error

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.CircularDependencyError: main_app.0001_initial
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CircularDependencyError

The circular dependency error is encountered when a file being called is associated with a dependency, which has the file being called as its dependency.

In the file `main_app/001_initial.py`, you added the dependency `main_app/001_initial.py` by adding the line:

```
dependencies = [
    ('main_app', '0001_initial')
]
```

On migration, the confusion arises whether to import the file `main_app/001_initial.py` or the dependency `main_app/001_initial.py` whose dependency is the file `main_app/001_initial.py`.
Hence, creating a circular dependency pattern.

### Adding default values.

Adding multiple rows of data from migration file is not part of a good coding paradigm. You would want to use a different method.

#### Add default values to model itself.

These values will only help to add default values when saving one instance at a time.

```
class Records(models.Model):
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=17, unique=True, default="ACCORD")
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.alias
```

Now there are multiple ways to populate the table with data.

1. Link the django app to the database with data rows already in place.
2. Add a serializer function BulkCreate to add values in bulk.
3. Use the command line shell manually to create model instances that would populate the database table. You can read about using `python manage.py shell` and `python manage.py shellplus`.
4. Use a python script to add the data by creating model instances with the desired values.

### Another tip

Instead of using a `list_data` function in `models.py`, using a django serializer would serve more functionality and is a better way to code.

The idea is to keep `models.py` as clean as possible with only the attribute definitions there.